# How to publish code to local phusion passenger install from development folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my local dev machine I am coding on (ubuntu), I am using the built in rails server (webrick):

```
rails s
```

I want to sometimes test things out on a local copy of phusion passenger that I am going to install.

How can I automate pushing the files to my phusion passenger server?

Would a simple script that copies the contents of the folder suffice? 
Is it easier to setup capistrano?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the folder would suffice (assuming all of your environment details are the same).

Personally I would just clone my git repository (not sure if you are using source control) into the appropriate folder.